# Determining where in a list ascending or descending stops

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a large list of continuous data, and I'm trying to figure out where the data increases for a minimum amount of entries and where it decreases. For example, if I have list

```
[0, 1, 3, 8, 10, 13, 13, 8, 4, 11, 5, 1, 0]
```

I want to be able to capture the runs of 0, 1, 3, 8, 10, 13, 13 and 11, 5, 1, 0 but not the run of 8, 4 (because it's less than the arbitrary amount 3).

Currently I'm using ascending and descending functions to capture a certain number of the runs at a time (0, 1, 3 and 1, 3, 8, for example), but it doesn't get the entire length in a single list.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Loop over the list. Use variables to keep track of (a) the current run and (b) the direction of the current run. When the current run ends, check that it is long enough (and if so output it), then start a new run. I think the most complicated case to handle is when you hit the second `8` and output the ascending run which terminates there. Is there a new run descending of length 3 (`13, 13, 8`), or are runs not allowed to overlap? Either way, you account for it in how you set up the new run.

Comment: The complicated case might be solved by always tracking an ascending and descending run in parallel. Each run will be stopped, when the next number does go down for an ascending run and vice-versa.

Comment: I've implemented both the simple and complicated cases; @dornhege, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @AFL: just curious, but what made you make the choice as to which answer as accepted? I mean, I'd really like to konw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work... it breaks the data into disjoint monotonic subsequences and then filters by your length criteria.

```
def get_monotonic_subsequences(data, min_length):
    direction = data[1] - data[0] #determine direction of initial subsequence
    subsequences = []
    cur_seq = []
    for i in range(0, len(data) - 1):
        if direction > 0:
            if (data[i] >= data[i-1]):
                cur_seq.append(data[i])
            else:
                subsequences.append(cur_seq)
                cur_seq = [data[i]]
                direction = data[i+1] - data[i]
        else:
            if (data[i] <= data[i-1]):
                cur_seq.append(data[i])
            else:
                subsequences.append(cur_seq)
                cur_seq = [data[i]]
                direction = data[i+1] - data[i]

    if  (data[-1] - data[-2])*direction > 0:
        cur_seq.append(data[-1])
        subsequences.append(cur_seq)
    else:
        subsequences.append(cur_seq)
        subsequences.append([data[-1]])
    return [x for x in subsequences if len(x) >= min_length]
```

As an aside, it's not clear from your question, but your output suggests that you expect the subsequences to be collected greedily from left to right, which this code assumes.

Comment: `[x for x in subsequences if len(x) >= min_length]` would be considered idiomatic; `filter()` is now discouraged in most cases.

Comment: our versions seem to perform almost identically: yours ~8.5us, mine ~9.5us!

Comment: Should one of those direction = -1 be direction = 1?

Comment: @AFL- Yes, that's what I meant :P But even better, your comment pointed out a more serious bug; I wasn't handling direction changes at the end of input correctly. I've updated the code with the fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Monotonic without overlaps:**

This version finds monotonic sequences and doesn't register overlaps; sorry for not having paid attention initially.

```
def find_sequences(lst, min_len=3):
    curr = []
    asc = None
    for i in lst:
        if not curr or len(curr) == 1 or asc and i >= curr[-1] or not asc and i <= curr[-1]:
            if len(curr) == 1:
                asc = curr[-1] < i
            curr.append(i)
        else:
            if len(curr) >= min_len:
                yield curr
            asc = None
            curr = [i]
    if len(curr) >= min_len:
        yield curr
```

yields:

```
[[0, 1, 3, 8, 10, 13, 13], [11, 5, 1, 0]]
```

with performance:

```
In [6]: timeit list(find_sequences(x))
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.44 µs per loop
```

**Monotonic/non-monotonic with overlaps:**

This function finds monotonic & overlapping sequences; you can easily change it to work non-monotonically by changing `>=` and `<=` to `>` and `<` respectively, or even make it parametrizable.

```
def find_sequences(lst, min_len=3):
    asc, desc = [], []
    for i in lst:
        if not asc or i >= asc[-1]:
            asc.append(i)
        else:
            if len(asc) >= min_len:
                yield asc
            asc = [i]

        if not desc or i <= desc[-1]:
            desc.append(i)
        else:
            if len(desc) >= min_len:
                yield desc
            desc = [i]

    if len(desc) >= min_len:
        yield desc
    if len(asc) >= min_len:
        yield asc
```

yields:

```
[[0, 1, 3, 8, 10, 13, 13], [13, 13, 8, 4], [11, 5, 1, 0]]
```

with performance:

```
In [3]: timeit list(find_sequences(x))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop
```